# What is the difference between view Holder and view Model?

Tags: android, mvvm

What is the difference between view Holder and view Model?

I want to know what are the main difference between these with exmaple.

Comment: You can not differentiate two things which are not related at all because they are completely different that's the only difference .  Just because their name starts with view does not make them related.

Answer (score 3):

A `ViewHolder` is used in recyclerviews (which, well, recycles views) and is a representation of how one complete entry into a recyclerview will look.

A `Viewmodel` is an architecture component, which is typically lifecycle aware, so it helps you to save the state of certain data between different configurations and (potentially) different screens